# Rehash in python

Tags: python, hash

I am trying to read lines from a file which contains hashed data.
The data was hash with the following code:

```
encoder = hashlib.sha224()
encoder.update(string)
file.write(encoder.hexdigest())
```

how do I rehash the data?

Comment: Rehash? That is an one-way function, or you want to crack it?

Comment: If by *rehash* you mean reconstruct the data from the hash - that's not possible. This is the whole point of secure hash-functions.

Comment: so how can I hash string to key and do the other way (key to string)?
I can change the way this file is written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, you can't do that, and that's the actual idea behind hashing. I think what you are really looking for is [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption).

When the data is encrypted, nobody can read it. Only when you know how to decrypt it, you can read it again. There are many different ways of encryption, such as symmetric and asymmetric, just read about it, or supply more information about what you are really trying to do so we can tell you what encryption you should use.